# Is there a word for the totality of existence?

Tags: single-word-requests

"Universe" doesn't mean everything in existence, because there might be multiple. "Multiverse" doesn't either, because different dimensions could have different multiverses. Is there a word that describes the totality of literally everything that exists?

Comment: Other than God, _creation_. Atheists might prefer EE ('Doc') Smith's 'Cosmic All'.

Comment: Remember, it's all in "your mind".

Comment: Why don’t you define it as ***All*** with a capital ‘A’?

Comment: "But listen, it’s not finished; the United States of America; Continent of North America; Western Hempisphere; the Earth; the Solar System; the Universe; the Mind of God." Thornton Wilder's play: Our Town

Comment: Uncommon word but intent is recognizable: omniverse

Comment: Under what illogical scheme would you separate different dimensions from the label 'multiverse'?

Comment: @Jim Best so far, but the unqualified *all* or *everything* would suffice. (*Unqualified* here means *without qualifiers*.)

Comment: I think the best answer is *reality*. It's even a better word than *existence*. Since this question is closed, I can't make this an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, and that word is ... *existence*.

> Noun: **existence**  ig'zis-tun(t)s or eg'zis-tun(t)s
>
> 1. The state or fact of being objectively real
>      "laws in existence for centuries"; - being, beingness
> 2. **Everything that exists anywhere
>      "the biggest tree in existence"; - universe, creation, world, cosmos, macrocosm**
>
>    -- [WordWeb Online](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=existence)

Comment: This deserves more upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

> "Universe" doesn't mean everything in existence

Actually, that is exactly what it means.

> **universe**
>
> u·ni·verse
>
> ˈyo͞onəˌvərs
>
> noun
>
> all existing matter and space considered as a whole; the cosmos. The universe is believed to be at least 10 billion light years in diameter and contains a vast number of galaxies; it has been expanding since its creation in the Big Bang about 13 billion years ago.
>
> synonyms:  cosmos, macrocosm, totality; infinity, all existence, Creation; space, outer space, firmament
>
> "the physical universe"
>
> a particular sphere of activity, interest, or experience.
>
> plural noun: universes
>
> "the front parlor was the hub of her universe"
>
> synonyms:  world, sphere, domain, preserve, milieu, province
>
> "the universe of computer hardware"
>
> another term for universal set.
>
> noun: universe of discourse; plural noun: universes of discourse
>
> [google: universe definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=Universe&oq=Universe&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=universe+definition)

The universe is everything.  Just that, everything.  You can put limits on it and then ask what's beyond those limits but if anything really is beyond those limits it was the limits that were wrong.  It's only through toying with those limits that we get ideas like

> **multiverse**
>
> cosmology
>
> :  a theoretical reality that includes a possibly infinite number of parallel universes
>
> [merriam-webster: multiverse](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiverse)

If multiverses truly exist then they're actually just a part of the universe.  The limits we had placed on the universe are what need to be redefined.

If you doubt this consider, universe is supposed to mean everything.  Whatever new word you could come up with to mean everything can be subverted exactly the same way universe was when people thought up multiverse.  If you use "foo" to mean everything including parallel universe and limit it that way then someone could just think up the "multifoo" theory.

The only thing that makes the universe less than the multiverse is that the universe is standard model science.  Multiverse is an unproven idea.  Prove the multiverse exists and you've redefined the universe.

If the universe is not infinite, people will always wonder what is outside of it.
If it is infinite, people will always wonder how to get away from it.

Answer (score 3):

Despite its rejection in the question, "universe" *by definition* means the totality of existence.

Comment: That [depends on which definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse) you use. In the context of the OP's question, we're talking about a universe which exists within a set of multiverses, so your definition is specifically excluded. In such a scenario, "totality of existence" can't possibly be the definition of universe, because it would contradict the definition of multiverse.

Answer (score 2):

### [Omniverse](http://www.yourdictionary.com/omniverse)

> n. A number of supposedly co-existing universes

Considering the fact that we do not know if other universes actually exist, I think it calls for a definition related to science fiction.

[Marvel wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Omniverse) explains (emphasis mine):

> **The Omniverse is the collection of every single universe, multiverse,
>   megaverse, dimension (alternate or pocket) and realm.** This includes
>   not only Marvel Comics, but also DC Comics, Image, Dark Horse, Archie,
>   Harvey, and every universe ever mentioned or seen (and an infinite
>   amount never mentioned or seen) including our own world. Everything is
>   in the Omniverse, and there is only one Omniverse. According to the
>   Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe: Alternate Universes, "It
>   includes every single literary, television show, movie, urban legend,
>   universe, realm, etc. ever. It includes everyone from Popeye to Rocky
>   Balboa to Ronald Reagan to Romeo and Juliet to Luke Skywalker to
>   Snoopy to Jay and Silent Bob, Mickey Mouse, Harry Potter, Super Mario
>   to Sonic the Hedgehog, etc." This includes universes outside of
>   comics, such as Star Wars, Dragon Ball Z, Hunger Games and Assassin's
>   Creed. The Omniverse is EVERY reality, including those published by
>   all other companies. Even fan-fictions, cancelled works, mere
>   fantasies, wishes of thoughts created by people, and fictional
>   universes yet to be published are considered part of the Omniverse,
>   simply put the **Omniverse is every version of reality and existence
>   imaginable.**

Answer (score 1):

How about "cosmos"? 
No such thing as a "multi-cosmos", as far as I know    :)

Comment: Well my flatmate has just suggested "the whole enchilada"...

Comment: Yeah, but what kind of sauce?

Comment: Ha ha. Good one. Enchiladas always have the same sauce, if you know Mexican food at all.....

Comment: @Lambie - Maybe you don't know all enchiladas.  How do you know what sauce is used on Beta Omicron 4?

Comment: Enchiladas do not always have the same sauce.

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality for its shortness and content (possibly automatically; the system sometimes does that). Please consider adding some sources or some more discussion. The plural of cosmos, "cosmoses" or "cosmoi," is used, although it is less common than the plural of "universe": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=universes+%2F+universe%2C(cosmoses+%2B+cosmoi)+%2F+cosmos&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28universes%20/%20universe%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28%28cosmoses%20%2B%20cosmoi%29%20/%20cosmos%29%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

I think this might do:

"The macrocosm is everything that exists: it's another word for the universe or cosmos. If you know that micro means "small" and macro means "large," that can help you remember the meaning of this word: the macrocosm is the largest thing there is, since it's a word for everything in existence." - [Source](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/macrocosm)

Compare with microcosm: "A small, representative system having analogies to a larger system in constitution , configuration, or development" - [Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/microcosm)

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with a flowery adjective and the word *existence* itself.

"The absolute entirety of all existence, knowable and un-knowable"
"The womb of existential reality"
"Existence," even

Comment: existential sounds human related to my ear....as for womb, well....not so convinced of that because now you have a body...